# Convert acres into square footage in one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio, and I need to convert acreage into square feet in one of the columns in my table. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to _display_ the square footage or _change_ your database column to square footage?

Comment: If you want to just display the sq.ft. value, just do an aliased calculation in your select > `SELECT myAcres * 43560 AS sqFt ....`. If you need to update the db value, see the below answers. But make sure you also change the calculation where that field is being entered into your db, or you'll have a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure precisely what you are asking, as this solution seems too trivial;

```
select my_sq_foot_column/43500 my_acres from my_table.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to update it you can use:

```
UPDATE ACRES_TABLE
   SET ACRES_COLUMN = ACRES_COLUMN * 43560;
```